# Карусель с центральным слайдом и другим css

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, css-animation

Привет! Учусь верстать, и на странице нужно сверстать карусель, да не простую, вот как она должна выглядеть:

[image: Пример карусели]

Суть в том, что на экране 5 слайдов, то что по центру должен выводить дополнительную информацию. Думаю как лучше решить эту задачу.

Пока что решил сделать это с помощью [jquery slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). Эта карусель в настройках имеет свойство `centerMode: true`, которое в том числе, добавляет класс центральному слайду `.slick-center`, и в css можно прописать стили что бы выводилась информация по центру и скрывалась круглая фото (или менялись ее размеры, позиция и `border-radius`).

В результате, по сути выйдет, что в каждом слайде будет два блока div, один будет скрыт, а другой показан, в зависимости от того, центральный он или боковой.

Коллеги в верном ли я направлении или, как обычно, изобретаю велосипед?

Comment: Как запасной вариант - [Owl Carousel 2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html#center) тоже даёт класс `.center` центральному элементу: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/Xjryjd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал вам небольшой шаблончик, остальное уже сами стилизуете:

```css
.owl-item.active.center img{
  height: 260px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.2.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.2.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="owl-carousel">
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x300/936/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x300/693/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x300/369/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
      <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x300/f63/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
  </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.2.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    center: true,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```